# time seri from long to wide

Tags: r, time-series, pivot

I have a data frame like

| date. | precipitation. |
| --- | --- |
| 1950-01-01 | 2.5 |
| 1950-01-02 | 1.5 |
| . | . |
| . | . |
| 2021-12-30 | 1.5 |
| 2021-12-31 | 1 |

I want to have data frame like this :

| year | month | 1 | 2 | . | . | 30 | 31 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1950 | 01 | 2.5 | 1.5 | . | . | 3 | 3.25 |
| 1950 | 02 | 2 | 1.7 | . | . | 3.1 | 3.5 |
| . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . |
| . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . |
| 2021 | 11 | 2.5 | 1.5 | . | . | 3 | 3.25 |
| 2021 | 12 | 2.3 | 1.67 | . | . | 1.7 | 1.5 |

I would appreciate it if some one could help me. thanks in advance

I extracted month, day, and year in separate columns and use pivot wider:

```
wide_table <- pivot_wider(df, names_from = day, values_from = value, names_prefix = "Day_", values_fill = NA)
```

but the result is not exactly the format that I want

Comment: And what have you done so far? Nothing?

Comment: I extracted month, day, and year in separate columns and use pivot wider:
  wide_table <- pivot_wider(df, names_from = day, values_from = value, names_prefix = "Day_", values_fill = NA)

but it is not exactly the format that I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problems like this, split the date up into separate columns **first**, then use `pivot_wider`:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(date = c('1950-01-01', '1950-01-02'),
               precip = c(2.5, 1.5))

data

date       precip
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 1950-01-01    2.5
2 1950-01-02    1.5

data.wide <- data %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date),
         year = year(date),
         month = month(date),
         day = day(date)) %>% 
  select(-date) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = day, values_from = precip)

data.wide

# A tibble: 1 × 4
   year month   `1`   `2`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  1950     1   2.5   1.5
```

Also, this is a very common and standard problem that has **many** answers on both this website and others. It's worth developing your searching abilities, especially for usage of basic functions like `pivot_wider()`. And remember to include example data in your question, not a table, make it easy for your answerers!

Comment: Thank you.. but what was my problem ? since I almost did the same approach

Comment: Yes true, I think it's because you didn't remove the 'Date' column before you used pivot_wider(). If you're pivoting and you get lots of annoying NA's and diagonal lines of values, you usually need to remove a column that has unique IDs, like 'Date' in your case.

Though, I have to guess because you forgot to include an intermediate dataframe that you must have made.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're almost there - drop the date column first and it should work:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(date.  = c("1950-01-01", "1950-01-02", "1950-01-03"),
                 precipitation. = c(2.5, 1.5, 4)
                 )

df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    year = year(date.),
    month = month(date.),
    day = day(date.)
  )

df <- df %>%
  select(-date.)

wide_table <- pivot_wider(df, names_from = day, values_from = precipitation., names_prefix = "Day_", values_fill = NA)
```